# Python insert node function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a really hard time understanding how to properly fix my insert node function. I am not receiving any errors but I am also not displaying the list.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Solution:
    def display(self, head):
        current = head
        while current:
            print current.data,
            current = current.next

    def insert(self, head, data):
        self.head = head
        new_node = Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node

mylist = Solution()
T = int(input())
head = None
for i in range(T):
    data = int(input())
    head = mylist.insert(head, data)    
mylist.display(head)
```

Comment: Can u fix your indentation at `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your insert() didn't return anything. So head will be None if you assign returned value to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you want

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class Solution:
     def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def display(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            print current.data,
            current = current.next

    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node


mylist = Solution()
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    data = int(input())
    mylist.insert(data)
mylist.display()
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention in the original post due to the nature of this challenge I do not have access to editing any of the code except the insert function of the class Solution.